# When would indeterminate NULL in PL/SQL be useful?

Tags: plsql, null, comparison

I was reading some PL/SQL documentation, and I am seeing that `NULL` in PL/SQL is indeterminate.

In other words:

```
x := 5;
y := NULL;
...
IF x != y THEN  -- yields NULL, not TRUE
   sequence_of_statements;  -- not executed
END IF;
```

The statement would not evaluate to true, because the value of y is unknown and therefore it is unknown if `x != y`.

I am not finding much info other than the facts stated above, and how to deal with this in PL/SQL.  What I would like to know is, when would something like this be useful?

Comment: Feel free to use `IF nvl(x != y, true) THEN` to completely define behavior of `IF` the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is three valued logic, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic, and - specific for SQL - in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL).

It follows the concept that a `NULL` value means: this value is currently unknown, and might be filled with something real in future. Hence, the behavior is defined in a way that would be correct in all cases of future non-null values. E. g. `true or unknown` is `true`, as - no matter if the `unknown` (which is the truth value of `NULL`) will later be replaced by something that is true or something that is false, the outcome will be `true`. However, `true and unknown` is `unknown`, as the result will be true if the `unknown will later be replaced by a true value, while it will be false, if the`unknown` will later be replaced by something being false.

And finally, this behavior is *not "non determinictic"*, as the result is well defined, and you get the same result on each execution - which is by definition deterministic. It is just defined in a way that is a bit more complex than the standard Boolean two-valued logic used in most other programming languages. A non-deterministic function would be `dbms_random.random`, as it returns a dfferent value each time it is called, or even `SYSTIMESTAMP`, which also returns different values if called several times.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said indeterminate, not non-deterministic - I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You can find good explanation why NULL was introduced and more in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29).

In PL/SQL you deal with NULL by

- using `IS (NOT) NULL` as a comparision, when you would like to test against NULL
- using `COALESCE` and `NVL` functions, when you want to substitute NULL with something else, like here `IF NVL(SALARY, 0) = 0`